# I am getting couldn't build model error in einstein bot

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I am getting couldn't build model error in einstein bot. I have 9 intents on every intents  i added around 50 utterances.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suspect the issue is occurring due to duplicate utterances.Can you query all utterances using`SELECT id, Utterance FROM MlIntentUtterance` and do de-dupe through excel. If you find any, please remove all the duplicates and make sure that the total utterances on a given intent should be more than 20 after removing the duplicates. Let me know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: @Swetha Thanks there was duplicate utterances added due to that this issue was coming now it is solved. But i have one question. Bot is asking question and giving me two choice Yes and NO instead of selecting that choice i am asking a random question so bot is not giving any response and if i type the same question again then bot is responding so ideally bot should respond in first time only

Comment: Happy to know the proposed solution works. I'll post it as an answer so it can help other users in the future.  I'd suggest posting the follow-up question as a new one with more details on the expected vs actual response.

Comment: Hi@Swetha, Can you please check this question once if you have any idea on this please suggest- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400676/how-to-end-the-chatbot-session-from-lwc-component

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments section, the issue was occurring due to duplicate utterances.

To remove the duplicates you can query all utterances using `SELECT id, Utterance FROM MlIntentUtterance`  and you can download them through Dataloader or Workbench. Then do de-dupe through excel.

If you find any, please remove all the duplicates and make sure that the total utterances on a given intent are more than 20 after removing the duplicates.

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_model_mgmt.htm&type=5) ,

> A minimum of 20 utterances is required to build the model, but more utterances make the model more accurate.